# Why to prevent canActivate from always returning false?

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication

I have been searching in order to avoid duplicated posting etc. and did give some solutions a try, but was not successful to fix the issue.

I use canActivate to protect a dashboard and it works fine except that it always returning false so that I can never access the protected routers.

I don't get any error or something similar so that I can localize and fix.
the `isAuthenticated` is always being set to false and doesn't get the result of the function: `setAuthenticated()` which is changing it to: `true`.

Any idea please?

**`auth.service.ts`**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    public isAuthenticated = false;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    setUserLoggedIn() {
        this.isAuthenticated = true;
    }

    getUserLoggedIn() {
        return this.isAuthenticated;
    }

    public setAuthenticated() {

        this.http
            .get<any>(url, {withCredentials: true, observe: 'response'})
            .subscribe(
                (res) => {
                    console.log('Status: Authenticated: ' + res.headers.get('status') );
                    if ( res.headers.get('status') === '200') {
                        this.setUserLoggedIn();
                    }
                },
                err => {});
    }
}
```

**`authguard.guard.ts`**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate,
         ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
         RouterStateSnapshot,
         Router,
         ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from './service/auth.service';


@Injectable()
export class AuthguardGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private user: AuthService,
        public router: Router,
        private http: HttpClient,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    canActivate( route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

        if ( !this.user.isAuthenticated ) {
            console.log('Not authenticated!');
            this.router.navigate(['userLogin']);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look when is the method "setAuthenticated" is getting called.
If you call this method, it gets the response after some time (network call) till that time the value of the isAuthenticated  will be false

Comment: Exactly! and it this is where I'am struggling... how to force canActivate to wait till the `setAuthenticated ` is being invoked and the new value of `isAuthenticated ` is set to true.

Comment: the value start on false in the auth service, do you ever change to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use Observable in Auth-Guard. Like below:

In auth.service.ts, change "setAuthenticated" method as below.

```
public setAuthenticated() {
// YOU SHOULD SET "isAuthenticated" value to FALSE when the session is over.
if (this.isAuthenticated === true) {
    return Observable.of(true);
} else {
    return this.http.get<any>(url, {withCredentials: true, observe: 'response'})
      .map((res) => {
        if ( res.status === 200) {
             this.isAuthenticated = true;
             return true;
        } else {
            this.isAuthenticated = false;
            console.log('Not authenticated!');
            this.router.navigate(['userLogin']);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
}
```

authguard.guard.ts:

```
// All imports
@Injectable()
export class AuthguardGuard implements CanActivate {
constructor(
    private user: AuthService,
    public router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
}

canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
   return this.user.setAuthenticated()
     .map((res) => {
        if ( res === true) {
             return true;
        } else {
            console.log('Not authenticated!');
            this.router.navigate(['userLogin']);
            return false;
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll give tit a try... one question pls. for what is the `params `?

Comment: @k.vincent , Params include any parameters you want to send to that method. I have edited the answer, check it

Comment: Unfortunately always going to login ;-(

Comment: Put console logs and trace the code in dev mode. 
Make sure `res.headers.get('status)` returns the value `'200'`

Comment: if I add: `alert(res.headers.get('status'));` in the service after after: `return this._http.get<any>(environment.urlUserInfo, {withCredentials: true, observe: 'response'})
              .map((res) => {...`, I get `null`. But after the page is loaded I see  that the header status is `200`and response is fine

Comment: @BasavarajBhusani: I think the moment is the response still not available.. that's why `null`

Comment: You should add alerts/logs after `.map((res) => { console.log(res); }`. check the values.

Comment: If I add this in service after `.map(...)` `console.log(JSON.stringify (res) + 'header: ' + res.headers.get('status'));` it gives me the whole response where I can see headers with status `200`, but then it's `null`.
if I add this after `.map(...)` `console.log( 'in Guard ' + JSON.stringify (res) );` in authguard, it gives me: `false`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167208/discussion-between-k-vincent-and-basavaraj-bhusani).

Comment: @BasavarajBhusani I'm having similar issue, can you please take a look? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74424097/why-angular-guards-can-activate-always-returns-false